# Fail to extend a Layout view in Backbone Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I created a view like this:

```
var MyView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    template: #someTemplate,
    regions: function() {
        return {
            someRegions: '.Regions',
        };
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
        if (options) {
            do stuff...
        }
    },

    onRender: function() {
        var titleBar = new Bar({ options: "options" });
        this.barRegion.show(titleBar);
    }
});
```

Which is basically a view that has a top bar with some buttons.

Now, I need to create a whole bunch of different views that have the same top bar, so I want to be able to do something like this:

```
var SecondView = MyView.extend({

    template: #template,

    onRender: function() {
        create content below top bar here...
    }
});
```

When I add breakpoints I see that MyView's initialize & render functions DO NOT get called, only my SecondView's initialize and render functions get called.

So the top bar does not show up, in fact MyView's template does not appear. Only SecondView shows up.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you not including all the relevant code? I don't see any initialize or render method defined for SecondView, so when you say "only my SecondView's initialize and render functions get called" what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone who tried to help me with this...

So for whoever might be interested in what I was trying to do, this is how I got it to work:

From SecondView's initialize method I had to call MyView's initialize method:

```
initialize: function(options) {

        MyView.prototype.initialize.call(this, options);

    }
```

Then, from SecondView's onRender method I had to call MyView's onRender method:

```
onRender: function() {

        MyView.prototype.onRender(this);

        // extra content for my SecondView goes here...

        var secondViewContent = new Content();
        this.someRegionInMyView.show(secondViewContent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `onRender` method on your second view is overriding the first one, so only your `SecondView.onRender` code is executed.

I think you're taking the wrong approach here. Create a Layout that includes the common topbar, and add another region for the views that go below that. If that view is another Layout is OK.

Graphically:

MainLayout
 --Topbar Region
 --SecondBar Region

You can make your MainLayout be the Application regions, and use your router or whatever mechanism to load the needed view into the SecondBar region.

Hope it makes sense. ;)

If you insist on using inheritance, then call a second method from your MainView onRender, something like:

```
onRender: function() {
  var titleBar = new Bar({ options: "options" });
  this.barRegion.show(titleBar);
  //hook for child views
  this.triggerMethod("onSecondRender");
}
```

And then move your `onRender` code to `onSecondRender` on your child views.